# Executing specific SQL to fill up a Database in springboot + Testcontainers

Tags: spring, testing, testcontainers

I'd like to execute some `sql` scripts to fill up my database for my integration tests. For now with the help of `TestContainers` and `data.sql` & `schema.sql` in my `tests/resources` folder, it's working, but those data filled by `data.sql` is shared with all my integration tests.

I'd like to execute some `sql` specifically dedicated to each integration tests.

Is there a facility to do so?

Else I will execute some `sql` directly inside my integration test to fill up what I need.

Comment: You can find various data [initialization strategies for Testcontainers here](https://rieckpil.de/initialization-strategies-with-testcontainers-for-integration-tests/).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at item 5 [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql). You can use an annotation on a test to load data for that test. Just keep in mind that data will stay for the duration of the test suite run unless you clean it.

Comment: Marvellous ! Thanks